# Misleading(?) TypeError when passing keyword arguments to function defined with positional arguments

Tags: python, arguments

In cPython 2.4:

```
def f(a,b,c,d):
    pass

>>> f(b=1,c=1,d=1)
TypeError: f() takes exactly 4 non-keyword arguments (0 given)
```

but:

```
>>> f(a=1,b=1,c=1)
TypeError: f() takes exactly 4 non-keyword arguments (3 given)
```

Clearly, I don't **really really** understand Python's function-argument processing mechanism.  Anyone care to share some light on this?  I see what's happening (something like filling argument slots, then giving up), but I think this would foul up a newbie.

(also, if people have better question keywords -- something like "guts" -- please retag)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what were you expecting Python to do in the two examples you gave?

Comment: I'd expect it to say 3 given to both.

Answer (score 13):

When you say

```
def f(a,b,c,d):
```

you are telling python that `f` takes 4 *positional* arguments. Every time you call `f` it must be given exactly 4 arguments, and the first value will be assigned to `a`, the second to `b`, etc.

You are allowed to call `f` with something like

`f(1,2,3,4)` or `f(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)`, or even `f(c=3,b=2,a=1,d=4)`

but in all cases, exactly 4 arguments must be supplied.

`f(b=1,c=1,d=1)` returns an error because no value has been supplied for `a`. (0 given)
`f(a=1,b=1,c=1)` returns an error because no value has been supplied for `d`. (3 given)

The number of args given indicates how far python got before realizing there is an error.

By the way, if you say

```
def f(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4):
```

then your are telling python that `f` takes 4 *optional* arguments. If a certain arg is not given, then its default value is automatically supplied for you. Then you could get away with calling

`f(a=1,b=1,c=1)` or `f(b=1,c=1,d=1)`

Comment: So, this is exactly the non-obvious part:  **The number of args given indicates how far python got before realizing there is an error.**  I'd file this under "wart that can bite novices", since in fact, 3 are given in both cases.

Comment: What about making a call wrapper that would catch such error and raise a more appropriate error? I've tried doing that but there's huge amount of little problematic details; has anyone else tried? (also, I wonder why it's not done in the default CPython)

Comment: "The number of args given indicates how far python got before realizing there is an error." is the key here.

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible to wrap the resulting TypeError with something more clear and informative. However, there are many little details some of which I don't know how to solve.

**NOTE:** the code below is a barely-working example, not a complete solution.

```
try:
    fn(**data)
except TypeError as e:
    ## More-sane-than-default processing of a case `parameter ... was not specified`
    ## XXX: catch only top-level exceptions somehow?
    ##  * through traceback?
    if fn.func_code.co_flags & 0x04:  ## XXX: check
        # it accepts `*ar`, so not the case
        raise
    f_vars = fn.func_code.co_varnames
    f_defvars_count = len(fn.func_defaults)
    ## XXX: is there a better way?
    ##  * it catches `self` in a bound method as required. (also, classmethods?)
    ##  * `inspect.getargspec`? Imprecise, too (for positional args)
    ##  * also catches `**kwargs`.
    f_posvars = f_vars[:-f_defvars_count]
    extra_args = list(set(data.keys()) - set(f_vars))
    missing_args = list(set(f_posvars) - set(data.keys()))
    if missing_args:  # is the case, raise it verbosely.
        msg = "Required argument(s) not specified: %s" % (
          ', '.join(missing_args),)
        if extra_args:
            msg += "; additionally, there are extraneous arguments: %s" % (
              ', '.join(extra_args))
        raise TypeError(msg, e)
        #_log.error(msg)
        #raise
    raise
```